ch.qos.logback.classic plugin is loaded but not detected in my Eclipse RCP app
I was given an Eclipse RCP application which contains a MyApp.product file as you can see here:
Now, if I click on product configuration (highlighted in red) it seems that many plug-ins are missing, e.g. org.jdom2, org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis and so on:

For this reason, I downloaded their jars. For instance, I downloaded jdom2.jar from this respository clicking on the red button:

Next, I pasted them into eclipse_rcp_dev/plugins directory.

Unfortunately, some plug-ins get detected my Eclipse IDE but others are not (e.g. org.jdom2 still is not detected by Eclipse IDE). Clicking on Add required plug-ins won't solve the issue.
What am I missing? If you need further information, e.g. the manifest file or other stuff, tell me.
EDIT
I set a target platform as you can see here (I both created a target platform and added some plug-ins from the file-system):

And activated it:

This is the generated my-target-definition.target file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="my-target-definition" sequenceNumber="10">
    <locations>
        <location path="C:\Users\quirilea\Desktop\eclipse_rcp_dev\plugins" type="Directory"/>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.orbit.maven.osgi.all.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240227-0900"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.orbit.maven.osgi.all.source.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240227-0900"/>
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/maven-osgi/release/4.31.0/"/>
        </location>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature.feature.group" version="1.4.203.v202104080213"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature.feature.group" version="1.5.201.v202301061019"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.101.v202308172102"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="3.7.0.v202308172102"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jpt.jpadiagrameditor.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.300.v202307260736"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group" version="3.13.0.v202308300413"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt.feature.group" version="3.29.0.v202308161955"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401080452"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group" version="2.8.0.v202307262303"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.900.v202402192305"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401292308"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.4.500.v202401292331"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_js_support.feature.feature.group" version="3.32.0.v202309190220"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202402161256"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group" version="2.12.0.v202307262216"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.0.v202308010354"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group" version="1.1.1200.v202311232240"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.600.v202308010354"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.feature.feature.group" version="1.2.1000.v202311280000"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240217-1525"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.feature.group" version="2.3.1.20240203-0902"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.source.feature.group" version="2.3.1.20240203-0902"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.sdk.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240220-1109"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.1.20231024-1618"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.php.composer.feature.group" version="8.2.0.202311292129"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.php.feature.group" version="8.2.0.202311292129"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.rap.tools.feature.feature.group" version="3.28.0.20240306-1200"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node.feature.feature.group" version="1.0.7.202310251358"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.3.202311211923"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group" version="3.7.4.v202308161955"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.chromium.debug.feature.feature.group" version="0.7.0.v202307190351"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group" version="2.4.500.v202307190318"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202401292308"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_js_support.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202403030558"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.31.0.v202403030558"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group" version="3.33.0.v202402030243"/>
            <unit id="org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group" version="1.3.1500.v202307260701"/>
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>

Many plug-ins are detected properly now:

There are some plug-ins I still can't add, such as ch.qos.logback.classic or ch.qos.logback.core.
How do I solve?

You are missing having a target platform with which you don't have to download JARs manually. See all the nice tutorials to build an RCP application and make sure to build your RCP application with Tycho. Be also aware that not everything from Maven Central can be used directly as OSGi bundle/Eclipse plugin.

You can't use just any jar as a plugin - it must be set up as a OSGi bundle/plugin. Were you given a xxx.target file - that can be used to set up the target platform.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ list all the Vogella tutorials.

Eclipse orbit has a plug-in version of org.jdom2 - you really need to find the target platform that was used for this RCP.

As I already said on this question which seems to be about the same thing setting up an unkown RCP with no knowledge of RCP development is just plain hard and far too broad for Stack Overflow. If you have a a file with a .target extension that is a target platform definition.

@howlger and greg-449 I edited my post, please check it out. Thank you

The target platform is still missing. You might have a look at the Tycho example (target platform) or even a bit simpler my IDEalized project (target platform). And please take your time to work through the tutorials mentioned, as a basic understanding of OSGi, Eclipse and Tycho is required to develop an RCP application.

Eclipse repositories and Maven repositories are not the same thing. The logback plugins are available in Eclipse Orbit https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/maven-osgi/release/4.31.0/index.html

@greg-449 I added  https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/maven-osgi/release/4.31.0/ to "software site > work with" entry and added all its plugins, but ch.qos.logback.classic and ch.qos.logback.core are not detected by Eclipse IDE. I editeed my post, please check it out.

Feature org.eclipse.orbit.maven.osgi.all.feature.group does contain the logback plugins. You may need to Reload the target platform.

@greg-449 Already did it, but won't work. This is what I did: try to reload the target platform. Try to remove and re-add the https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/simrel/maven-osgi/release/4.31.0/ url. Try to clean project. Try to restart eclipse. Nothing works. Also clicked on "add required plug-ins"

Sorry, but I can't help any further with issues like this, they are impossible to diagnose in a S O question. Why do you not have the original target platform for the RCP? If the RCP is built using [tag:tycho] (which it has to be these days) it must already have a target platform as Tycho won't work without it, even without Tycho a target platform should have existed.

@greg-449 Ok, thank you. This is because I heredited this software where dependencies where loaded from a colleague's local file system...
